# How to set preferences for ALS implicit feedback in Collaborative Filtering?

Tags: scala, machine-learning, apache-spark, collaborative-filtering

I am trying to use Spark MLib ALS with implicit feedback for collaborative filtering. Input data has only two fields `userId` and `productId`. I have **no product ratings**, just info on what products users have bought, that's all. So to train ALS I use:

```
def trainImplicit(ratings: RDD[Rating], rank: Int, iterations: Int): MatrixFactorizationModel
```

(http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.0.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.ALS$)

This API requires `Rating` object:

```
Rating(user: Int, product: Int, rating: Double)
```

On the other hand documentation on `trainImplicit` tells: *Train a matrix factorization model given an RDD of 'implicit preferences' ratings given by users to some products, in the form of (userID, productID, **preference**) pairs.*

When I set rating / preferences to `1` as in:

```
val ratings = sc.textFile(new File(dir, file).toString).map { line =>
  val fields = line.split(",")
  // format: (randomNumber, Rating(userId, productId, rating))
  (rnd.nextInt(100), Rating(fields(0).toInt, fields(1).toInt, 1.0))
}

 val training = ratings.filter(x => x._1 < 60)
  .values
  .repartition(numPartitions)
  .cache()
val validation = ratings.filter(x => x._1 >= 60 && x._1 < 80)
  .values
  .repartition(numPartitions)
  .cache()
val test = ratings.filter(x => x._1 >= 80).values.cache()
```

And then train ALSL:

```
 val model = ALS.trainImplicit(ratings, rank, numIter)
```

I get RMSE 0.9, which is a big error in case of preferences taking 0 or 1 value:

```
val validationRmse = computeRmse(model, validation, numValidation)

/** Compute RMSE (Root Mean Squared Error). */
 def computeRmse(model: MatrixFactorizationModel, data: RDD[Rating], n: Long): Double = {
val predictions: RDD[Rating] = model.predict(data.map(x => (x.user, x.product)))
val predictionsAndRatings = predictions.map(x => ((x.user, x.product), x.rating))
  .join(data.map(x => ((x.user, x.product), x.rating)))
  .values
math.sqrt(predictionsAndRatings.map(x => (x._1 - x._2) * (x._1 - x._2)).reduce(_ + _) / n)
}
```

So my question is: to what value should I set `rating` in:

```
Rating(user: Int, product: Int, rating: Double)
```

for implicit training (in `ALS.trainImplicit` method) ?

**Update**

With:

```
  val alpha = 40
  val lambda = 0.01
```

I get:

```
Got 1895593 ratings from 17471 users on 462685 products.
Training: 1136079, validation: 380495, test: 379019
RMSE (validation) = 0.7537217888106758 for the model trained with rank = 8 and numIter = 10.
RMSE (validation) = 0.7489005441881798 for the model trained with rank = 8 and numIter = 20.
RMSE (validation) = 0.7387672873747732 for the model trained with rank = 12 and numIter = 10.
RMSE (validation) = 0.7310003522283959 for the model trained with rank = 12 and numIter = 20.
The best model was trained with rank = 12, and numIter = 20, and its RMSE on the test set is 0.7302343904091481.
baselineRmse: 0.0 testRmse: 0.7302343904091481
The best model improves the baseline by -Infinity%.
```

Which is still a big error, I guess. Also I get strange baseline improvement where baseline model is simply mean (1).

Comment: What is the `numPartitions` here? This is an interesting question. Also for implicit data can we really get an RMSE, RMSE is much better in 1-5 likert scale right?

Comment: could you please tell what would be the n here you are passing into for computeRMSE. Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the alpha confidence level. Default is 1.0: but try lower.

```
val alpha = 0.01
val model = ALS.trainImplicit(ratings, rank, numIterations, alpha)
```

Let us know how that goes.

Comment: Alpha is recommended to be << 1

Comment: how do you know that the alpha is supposed to be << 1. Where have you seen that? Somewhere in the documentation? I'm unable to find it.

Answer (score 1):

'rating' in class Rating is a double value.

According to
http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/ALS-implicit-error-pyspark-td16595.html, 
'rating' can be value > 1.

And according to
https://docs.prediction.io/templates/recommendation/training-with-implicit-preference/,
'rating' can be the number of observations for given user+item

Answer (score 0):

It's even more strange since you are training with the whole set instead of using the "training" subset

How well distributed is the original data? do you have a large number of items without a preference or items that are preferred a lot?

In "Collaborative Filtering for Implicit Feedback Datasets" the alpha used is 40, you might want to experiment with different values but